Cannot forward local email to external address with AWS SES and postfix
I would like to forward local messages to external address with postifx using a AWS SES as smartrelay.
I configured the aliases in /etc/aliases:
postmaster:    root
mylocaluser:  root
root:   myemail@myemail.com

I run newaliases
I set the smartrelay in /etc/psotifx/main.cf:
myhostname = mylocalhostname.local
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mylocalhostname.local, localhost   
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:AWSUSER:AWSKEY
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
header_size_limit = 4096000
relayhost = email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:587

Then I tried:
mail -v root

But I see this in mail logs:
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/pickup[3273432]: 2383441C8C: uid=1002 from=<mylocaluser>
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/cleanup[3293270]: 2383441C8C: message-id=<20241018101946.2383441C8C@mylocalhostname.local>
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/qmgr[3273433]: 2383441C8C: from=<mylocaluser@mylocalhostname.local>, size=398, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/cleanup[3293270]: 2831A41C8B: message-id=<20241018101946.2383441C8C@mylocalhostname.local>
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/qmgr[3273433]: 2831A41C8B: from=<mylocaluser@mylocalhostname.local>, size=534, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/local[3293272]: 2383441C8C: to=<root@mylocalhostname.local>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 2831A41C8B)
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/cleanup[3293270]: 2D51741C9E: message-id=<20241018101946.2D51741C9E@mylocalhostname.local>
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/bounce[3293273]: 2383441C8C: sender delivery status notification: 2D51741C9E
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/qmgr[3273433]: 2D51741C9E: from=<>, size=2113, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/qmgr[3273433]: 2383441C8C: removed
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/cleanup[3293270]: 2F3B341C8C: message-id=<20241018101946.2D51741C9E@mylocalhostname.local>
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/qmgr[3273433]: 2F3B341C8C: from=<>, size=2250, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/local[3293272]: 2D51741C9E: to=<mylocaluser@mylocalhostname.local>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 2F3B341C8C)
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/qmgr[3273433]: 2D51741C9E: removed
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/smtp[3293275]: 2F3B341C8C: to=<myemail@myemail.com>, orig_to=<mylocaluser@mylocalhostname.local>, relay=email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com[3.126.224.62]:587, delay=0.29, delays=0.01/0.01/0.25/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com[3.126.224.62] said: 501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/qmgr[3273433]: 2F3B341C8C: removed
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/smtp[3293274]: 2831A41C8B: to=<myemail@myemail.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com[3.126.224.62]:587, delay=0.56, delays=0.01/0.01/0.34/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 010701929f23f415-32c11c76-8ff9-4209-8e6d-9f98c00a231b-000000)
Oct 18 12:19:46 mylocalhostname postfix/qmgr[3273433]: 2831A41C8B: removed

As you can see there is a 501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command)) error, and the mail was not delivered to external email.
What I'm missing?

mylocalhostname.local is an invalid hostname. The .local domain is reserved for multicast DNS.

thnaks for the tip, I changed with another one and it doesn't work too

2F3B341C8C: from=<>, size=2250, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2F3B341C8C: to=<myemail@myemail.com>, orig_to=<mylocaluser@mylocalhostname.local>, relay=email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com[3.126.224.62]:587, delay=0.29, delays=0.01/0.01/0.25/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com[3.126.224.62] said: 501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command))

The bounced message was sent with the null sender address MAIL FROM: <>.
AWS SES won't accept MAIL FROM: <>.
The message seems to be a forwarded DSN notification.
2383441C8C: sender delivery status notification: 2D51741C9E 
2D51741C9E: to=<mylocaluser@mylocalhostname.local>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 2F3B341C8C)

Otherwise, your original message was successfully forwarded to the external address:
2831A41C8B: to=<myemail@myemail.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com[3.126.224.62]:587, delay=0.56, delays=0.01/0.01/0.34/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 010701929f23f415-32c11c76-8ff9-4209-8e6d-9f98c00a231b-000000)

